# How to make my !ban command work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

every time I do `!ban [user]`, the bot crashes and I don't know why, would be wonderful if some one could help

my code:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith("!ban")) {
  const author = message.author
  const messageContent = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
  if (!messageContent) { 
    return message.reply("please tell me who you would like me to ban!")
  } else {
    if (messageContent = author) {
      return message.reply("You cant ban yourself silly!")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without providing the error message, it is difficult to determine what is going on. However, you are using the [equality operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#equality_operators) incorrectly.

Currently, on the line `if (messageContent = author) {`, you have defined a variable inside of an if-statement.

The correct way of doing so would as as follows:

```js
if (messageContent === author) {
```

Full example:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith("!ban")) {
  const author = message.author
  const messageContent = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
  if (!messageContent) { 
    return message.reply("please tell me who you would like me to ban!")
  } else {
    if (messageContent === author) {
      return message.reply("You cant ban yourself silly!")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An enhacement of the code:

```js
const {content: messageContent, author} = message
const [command, content] = messageContent.split(' ')

if (command === '!ban') {
    if (!content) return message.reply('please tell me who you would like me to ban!')
    if (content === author) return message.reply("You cant ban yourself silly!")
    // rest of code
}
```